# Perforce : passing file extensions in a "diff" command

Tags: file, diff, perforce

I'm trying to execute a "diff" command in P4's command line tool on a subset of files.

I would like to diff files in a certain directory that correspond to a certain extension.

Is there any way to specify an extension with the "diff" command ?

From what I gather from the documentation, such a thing is not possible.

How would you do "diff" only for files with a certain extension ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if `diff` in particular allows for multiple files, but in general, P4 allows for wildcards via `...`, so for all `txt` files in a certain subdirectory, you could say

`//depot/stuff/whatever/....txt`

That will filter out all .txt files in this particular path.

Comment: No problem. Glad to help! Btw - if this works out for you, please take a moment and accept the answer. This will give both of us rep points. Take care!

Comment: Yup, just did! You really helped me out. :)